# The series $\sum a_nx^n$ with $a_n \ge 0$ for all $n$ and convergent at $R$ also converges at $-R$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show that if the series converges at $R$,then it also converges at $-R$.
What I have done is, since the given power series converges at $R$ (finite quantity), then by $n$-th term test $\lim a_nR^n=0$.
NOW I have replaced $R$ with $-R$ in the last equation which now  takes the form 
$\lim(-1)^na_nR^n=0 = \lim(-1)^n \cdot \lim a_nR^n=0 \to \lim a_nR^n=0$.
Does this imply convergence of the given power series at -R?
My question is, is this a proper proof? It feels as if I'm missing something important. ...
Know someone who can answer?

Comment: Please encapsulate math in dollar signs. It'll make it look nicer.

Comment: @orangeskid Huh? Try $a_n=1/n^2$.

Comment: @Did. Oh yes, my bad. Perhaps I confused it with a singular point. Have to delete it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let $c_n=a_n(-R)^n=(-1)^na_nR^n$. Then $|c_n|=a_nR^n$ since the $a_n$ are non-negative, so it follows that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |c_n| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nR^n$$ is a convergent series.

We know that any absolutely convergent series converges, i.e, $$\text{The convergence of }\;\;\;\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |c_n| \;\;\;\text{ implies the convergence of } \;\;\;\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n$$ Therefore $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n = \sum_{n=1}a_n(-R)^n$ is a convergent series, which is the desired result.

Comment: thanks for helping in this.

Comment: Will you please me  in pointing out my mistake in my proof?

Comment: So you're saying that $\sum (-1)^na_nR^n$ converges because $\lim a_n R^n = 0$? That doesn't logically follow. How did you deduce that?